# How to add my data (or a snippet of my data) from Stata?

Tags: stata

As the title notes, how can I add data here, to create better questions. I'm not seeing a help/FAQ page for that, but am sure there is one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata) with Stata tagged questions, click on *learn more...*, which will lead you to the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info). On this page various ways of sharing data are explained, among which:

1. `input`, to create toy data.

   Example:

```
input byte(id x y)
1 0 0
2 1 2
3 4 5
end
```

2. `sysuse`, to use datasets that come with Stata.

   Example:

```
sysuse auto
```

3. `dataex`, to share a snippet of your actual data. See `help dataex` on how to use it. If you're using Stata 14.1 or higher `dataex` is already part of your installation, otherwise type `ssc install dataex` to install.

Comment: I agree with this excellent advice. By the way, almost all the work on that tag Wiki was done by @Pearly Spencer. Yet further, the Statalist FAQ Advice is often relevant. See https://www.statalist.org/forums/help